# How do build a dynamic in operator SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want create simple select query with this flow chart:

1. declare todo variable
2. if todo equal 'all' then run

   ```
    select * 
    from temptable 
    where part in ('todo', 'done', 'doing')
   ```
3. if todo equal 'done' then run

   ```
    select *
    from temptable    
    where part in ('done', 'doing')
   ```

For that purpose I wrote this query:

```
declare @ToDo varchar(max)
set @ToDo = 'all';

select *
from tempTable
where [part] in (case 
                    when @todo = 'all' then (select 'todo', 'done', 'doing')
                 end)
```

but I get this error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filling in the blank here, but use normal boolean logic:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE (@Todo = 'All' AND Part IN ('todo','done','doing'))
   OR (@ToDo = 'Done' AND Part IN ('done','doing'))
```

Comment: With such hard-coded values, an `IF` would be better and avoid the recompile. The OP wants to use two different lists, not an optional `@Todo` parameter

Comment: There would be marginal performance improvement at best with an `IF` here, to be honest, @PanagiotisKanavos , considering the simplicity of the query.

Comment: I've amended the answer, @SaiAbhiramInapala, though you should have been able to work out the change :)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @ToDo NVARCHAR(max), @sql1 NVARCHAR(max), @sql2 NVARCHAR(max)

SET @ToDo = 'all'

SELECT @sql1 = N'select * from TempTable where Part in (''todo'',''done'',''doing'')'

SELECT @sql2 = N'select * from TempTable where Part in (''done'',''doing'')'

IF @ToDo = 'all'
    EXEC Sp_executesql @Sql1

IF @ToDo = 'done'
    EXEC Sp_executesql @Sql2
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not a model of clarity, the following code demonstrates a way of building the list of `in` values on-the-fly:

```
declare @TempTable as Table ( Part VarChar(10) );
insert into @TempTable ( Part ) values ( 'done' ), ( 'doing' ), ( 'did' ), ( 'todo' );

declare @ToDo as VarChar(10) = 'all';

select *
  from @TempTable
  where part in (
    select *
      from ( values ( 'done' ), ( 'doing' ) ) as Alice( Toklas )
      where @ToDo in ( 'all', 'done' )
    union all
    select 'todo'
      where @ToDo = 'all' );
```